# Python Sorting Data for loop and if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

```
data = ['cat', 'dog', 'None', 'Turtle', 'None']
new_data = []
for item in data:
    if item == 'None':
        new_data.append(data.index(item))
print new_data

>> [2,2]
```

How do I go about getting to this store new data as `[2,4]`? This is what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) while looping.  This will track both, the current item and its index:

```
[index for index, x in enumerate(data) if x == "None"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    if item == 'None':
        new_data.append(idx)
```

better yet, just use a list comprehension as in Sven's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
In [1]: data = ['cat', 'dog', 'None', 'Turtle', 'None']

In [2]: [i for i,val in enumerate(data) if val == 'None']
Out[2]: [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

data.index(item) only returns the position of first occurance of the item in your list.
You could simply do this:

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
  if data[i] == 'None':
    new_data.append(i)
```

this should give you the required output

OR

check out Sven's answer

Comment: why is my python spitting out [2, 2] when i do this your way ^?

Comment: @aaronphalen it should give [2,4]. It does for me.

Comment: @unni I agree, but got some odd reasons my python is spitting out [2,2]. I have tried opening a new shell and I get the same thing.  What could be the issue?

Comment: @aaronphalen i'm not sure. I think you should go with Sven's answer though. As Tim pointed out thats more Pythonic

Comment: @SvenMarnach: oops, you're right. I just double-checked it; lookup indeed is O(1). Thanks for setting me straight on this.